# Change background color from input

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm using angular. I have a input that looks like:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="newBook.color">
```

basically when this is changed, I want a div's background color to be changed.

My controller has some lines that look like:

```
$scope.newBook = {};
$scope.newBook.color = "";

$scope.color = ->
  return "background-color: " + $scope.newBook.color;
```

and then the div I want to change:

```
<div ng-style="{{color()}}"></div>
```

However, I get the error: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 17 of the expression [background-color:]`

Comment: Return style surrounded by {}

Comment: Try `<div ng-style="color()"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/chelogui/2h3hrj1x/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="appTest">
    <div ng-controller="contr as controller">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="controller.color" />
        <div id="divTest" style="background-color: {{ controller.color }}"></div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('appTest', [])
    .controller('contr', [function () {
    var self = this;
    self.color = "red";
}]);
```

Css to exemple:

```
#divTest {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/x3rSzw7XVn7ptxVp0n5V?p=preview):

You need to change your `color` function to do this:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
   .controller('myFirst',['$scope',function($scope){
      $scope.newBook = {};
      $scope.newBook.color = "red";
      $scope.color = function(){
        return "{'background-color' : '"+$scope.newBook.color+"'}";
      }
}])
```

Check this:

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myFirst',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.newBook = {};
    $scope.newBook.color = "red";
    $scope.color = function(){
        return "{'background-color' : '"+$scope.newBook.color+"'}";
    }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div  ng-controller="myFirst" ng-style="{{color()}}">Ajay</div></div>
```